# Why do i get this error, 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#

I am trying to get an input of #1-1-1 and I need to take the numbers from this string and put them into a list of type int. I have tried to do this using this code:

```
List<int>numbers = new List<int>();

numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split('-', '#').ToList().ConvertAll<int>(Convert.ToInt32);
```

Shouldn't the input get split into an array of the numbers I want, then get turned into a list, then get converted into a int list?

Comment: Skip the empty entries: `numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(new[] { '-', '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList().ConvertAll(Convert.ToInt32);`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the `.split('-','#')`. This splits the string into a string[] with four entrys (in this example). The first one is an empty string. This cannot be convertet into a Int32.

As a hotfix:

```
        var numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split('-', '#').ToList();
        //numbers.RemoveAt(0); <- this is also working
        numbers.Remove(string.Empty);
        var ret = numbers.ConvertAll<int>(Convert.ToInt32);
```

That will work for your "#1-1-1 " case. But you should check for non integer chars in the list before converting.

Answer (score 0):

string input = " #1-1-1";

```
var numbers = Console.ReadLine().Replace("#", "").Split('-').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
string[] separators = new string[] { "-", "#" };
numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(separators,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList().ConvertAll<int>(Convert.ToInt32);
```